# Add entries to web.config file of asp.net core application when web.config does not exist

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have an asp.net CORE project targeting .NET Framework 4.71

There is an appsettings.json file but not web.config.

When I check the binaries of the deployed application service, then I see there is

a file literally called web.config.

I need to put some server header removal entries in that web.config but it seems

only to be available where it is deployed.

So who is creating that web.config file which is not available locally in the

code solution?

Comment: What type of project is it? Did you use some of the [dotnet new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore22) templates to create it? What command do you use or how do you deploy the project?

Comment: It's done by `dotnet publish` (or the equivalent). If you create a `web.config` file in the root of your project, this will be used and updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regular .NET world, we have option to save settings in web.config or in app.config file. But in .NET Core, you have option to save them in few other locations like `appsettings.json` , `appsettings.<Environment>.json` and in `secrets.json`.

One of the main reason settings are not saved in web.config file is, to avoid settings getting checked-into repo. By default `appsettings.json` file are ignored by repo clients.

As Kirk said, the [dotnet-cli](https://rimdev.io/successfully-deploying-an-inprocess-aspnetcore-2-2-app-to-azure/) automatically creates this `web.config` based on the the csproj settings.