# How to create html/php webpage subdirectory in Azure Website?

Tags: php, html, css, azure, url-rewriting

I want the URL of my site to look like this 'https://example.com/mainPage/subPage/anotherSubPage' to have a better website directory. I am using Azure web app server and I can't seem to find the web.config folder even when using Advanced Tools.

[These are the contents of my \wwwroot folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGvZL.jpg).
I even searched it in every folders. Can't find them. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [`Kudu`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/azure-diagnose-application-startup-errors-with-kudu-console/), you can find the web.config under the folder **`\home\site\wwwroot`**.

Comment: I tried searching all the folders using the CMD in kudu. There isn't a web.config file there, even on the root folders.

Comment: do you have a web.config with your app

Comment: Nope. I don't deploy web.config files with my app

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code btw

Comment: then how do you expect it to be there?

Comment: Won't it automatically be created once deployed?

Comment: No it wont actually get created, whatever configurations needs to go to appserttings of the appservice.

Comment: Thank you. How do I create one using Visual Studio Code? Do I manually put the default configurations inside?

Comment: yeah you can do the same

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57982661/add-entries-to-web-config-file-of-asp-net-core-application-when-web-config-does

Comment: Thank you very much. I will probably need to learn rewriting to create subdirectories.

Comment: read my blog on the same https://sajeetharan.com/2020/01/11/deploy-web-app-to-a-sub-folder-on-azure/ mark if this answer helped

Comment: Gracias. I'm on the process of doing it now.